# SilverLight Elevated Privileges

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, security, silverlight-4.0

What are the capabilities of an elevated privilege OOB Silverlight Application? How low down is it able to communicate? I.e can you get to FileSystem areas, MAC addresses etc? The reason I ask is that I am looking at creating a security model for a Silverlight Business app, that would disallow one registered user installing the app on more than one machine, allowing as many users as they like to use the same license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key benefits include full keyboard access in full screen mode, COM interop, and cross-domain network access (i.e. you can access URIs from the application even if they don't have cross domain policieS). You also get more access to the file system, but the key is "more." You can access the user directories now ("My Documents", "My Pictures", etc) but you still don't get access to the full file system.